Microsoft 365 E5 developer subscription Eligibility
I have created Microsoft 365 Developer Program but unnable to create Microsoft 365 E5 developer subscription. Insted of setup options it is showing "Thank you for joining. You don't current qualify for a Microsoft 365 Developer Program sandbox subscription."
Could please tell me why i am not eligible?
And what do i need to for eligibility?
I tried useing another email also but got same problem.

Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?

see all developer-qualification information here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/microsoft-365-developer-program-faq

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

According to the below article new subscriptions are currently disabled, unless you buy a m365 subscription
. >_< .
I would say that "You do not qualify" message is misleading
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/stay-ahead-of-the-game-with-the-latest-updates-to-the-microsoft-365-developer-program/
